# How to get the positions of get_text in Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to store the result of my `get_text` in variables.

I am filtering my html in order to find the information I need. If I want to extract for example a number of rooted can present several, this is how the information I get is displayed:

```html
<span cetxt\"="" class='\"rSpnValor' vidc0='\"74922\"'>74922</span>
<span cetxt\"="" class='\"rSpnValor' vidc0='\"75005\"'>75005</span>
```

With get_text it would look like this:

```
74922
75005
```

I share a bit of my code:

```py
def getValBySpanName(name):
    dataArray = soup.find_all('div', {'class': '\\\"rDivDatosAseg'})
    for data in dataArray:
        data_container = data
        spans_data = data_container.find_all("span")
        info = []
        if spans_data[0].get_text() == name:
           container_values = spans_data[1].get_text()
           return container_values
       
file_number= getValBySpanName('Número de radicado')
print(file_number)
```

The problem is that I get the first position "74922" as a result. I need to find a way to store each value in the variable (Then I will insert this data in sql) so I need to save it one by one

I tried to go through them with a for but it goes through the positions of the first value, something like '7,4,9,2,2'

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are probably looking for something like this:

```
dataArray = soup.select('div.\\"rSpnValor span')
container_values = []
for data in dataArray:
    container_values.append(data.text)
print(container_values)
```

output

```
['74922', '75005']
```

Comment: I tried, but it returns the separate values ​​['74922']
                                                                 ['75005']

Comment: @DannyCamilo Then your sample html in the question doesn't reflect your actual html. Please update your question with s short, representative sample, and I'll try again.